# How to concatenate bytes and byte stream into a byte stream in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a binary string (bytes), and a potentially infinite byte stream. I need to concatenate them into a single byte stream in Python 3.6.

The concatenation must act like a standard byte stream, returning bytes from the string first, and then from the byte stream:

```
string = b'something'
stream = open(filename, 'rb')
concatenated = ?concat?(string, stream)  # <=== need this
x = concantenated.read(5)  # b"somet"
y = concatenated.read(2)  # b"hi"
z = concatentated.read(26)  # b"ngFIRST_24_BYTES_OF_STREAM"
…
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a class called `BufferedStringReader` which functions as a byte steam, reading the string first and then some infinite byte stream next. I have assumed that the byte stream you're talking about is a file, like a block device or character device. Those are the only infinite byte streams I'm aware of though.

A quick briefing of how I implemented it: My class was not inherited from `IOBase`, `BufferedReader` or any other python IO object because many of the members and methods had the same names. Since this class must act like both a string stream and a file stream, these objects are stored as members, my class does not inherit from them.

I decided against using the `tell()` method in `BufferReader` to implement position because there is a weird quirk when using `(some BufferReader object).tell()`: Instead of returning a positive number, it returns a value between the negative of some block size and 0. So when the file is opened, the position is zero, but when you start reading from it, the position is at -4096 + the actual position, which wraps around after reading 4096 bytes. And the block size may not even be 4096 on your system, so it's very wacky. (Let me know if it's different on yours.)

Also, since your question is about infinite byte streams, my class does not support writing. For the case of block devices which I had taken as an example, it's not supported anyway.

The final thing is that unlimited reads aren't supported because it's used with infinite streams anyway, such calls would run out of memory.

```
from io import BufferedReader, StringIO, UnsupportedOperation

# Because this is a read-only stream, write methods raise an exception.
class BufferedStringReader:
    def __init__(self, string, name, mode):
        if mode != 'rb' and mode != 'br':
            raise ValueError("invalid mode: " + mode)
        self.reader = open(name, mode)
        self.stringio = StringIO(string)
        self.string = string
        self.stringlen = len(string)
        self.readerpos = 0
        # self.reader.tell() doesn't seem to work properly
        self.pos = self.stringio.tell() + self.readerpos
        self.closed = (self.reader.closed and self.stringio.closed)

    # This is my own method, not a method in the io module
    def __update_state__(self):
        self.pos = self.stringio.tell() + self.readerpos
        self.closed = (self.reader.closed and self.stringio.closed)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{BufferedStringReader reader=" + str(self.reader) + " stringio=" + str(self.stringio) + "}"

    def getvalue(self):
        # Reads the entire file. Since this is an infinite byte stream this is not supported.
        raise UnsupportedOperation("BufferedStringReader does not support getvalue()")

    def close(self):
        self.reader.close()
        self.stringio.close()
        self.closed = True

    def flush(self):
        raise UnsupportedOperation("BufferedStringReader does not support flush()")

    # This function leaves the file stream in an undefined state
    def detach(self):
        self.reader.detach()
        #self.stringio.detach()  Not supported


    def isatty(self):
        return False

    def peek(self, size=0):
        # We cannot guarrentee one single read will be done in this class but
        # we can guarrentee that only one read will be done to the BufferedReader.
        # Note that the number of bytes returned may be less or more than requested.
        # Also in BufferedReader the size can apparently be negative and it's ignored
        # in any case (on my linux system it returns 4K bytes even for positive size).
        # Long story short; Python io's peek function ignores size.
        # Nevertheless, we *try* to return exactly size bytes.
        peek_size = (size if size > 0 else 1)
        string_pos = self.stringio.tell()
        string_read = self.string[string_pos:string_pos+peek_size]
        if len(string_read) < peek_size:
            reader_read = self.reader.peek(peek_size)
        else:
            reader_read = b''
        return (bytes(string_read, 'utf-8') + reader_read)[0:peek_size]

    def read(self, size=-1):
        # size=-1 will cause your machine to run out of memory since you're dealing with
        # and infinitely sized byte stream.
        if size <= -1:
            raise UnsupportedOperation("BufferedStringReader does not support read(size=-1)")

        string_read = ''
        reader_read = b''
        if self.pos <= self.stringlen and self.pos+size <= self.stringlen:
            string_read = self.stringio.read(size);

        elif self.pos <= self.stringlen and self.pos+size > self.stringlen:
            # No exceptions below, will return a smaller string if necessary
            string_read = self.stringio.read(size);
            reader_read = self.reader.read(size-len(string_read));

        elif self.pos > self.stringlen:
            reader_read = self.reader.read(size);

        else:
            # Impossible condition, detatch for security
            raise RuntimeError

        self.readerpos += len(reader_read)
        self.__update_state__()
        return bytes(string_read, 'utf-8') + reader_read;

    def readable(self):
        return True

    def read1(self, size=-1):
        # This is impossible to implement due to the arhitecture of this class.
        # This method is supposed to call read() exactly once but since there are
        # two IO streams, it is not possible.
        raise UnsupportedOperation("BufferedStringReader does not support read1()")

    def readinto(self, bytarray):
       temp_read = self.read(len(bytarray))
       temp_array = bytearray(temp_read)
       if len(temp_array) <= 0:
           return 0
       bytarray[0:len(temp_array)] = temp_array
       return len(temp_array)

    def readinto1(self, bytarray):
        raise UnsupportedOperation("BufferedStringReader does not support readinto1()")

    def readlines(self, size=-1):
        # Unlike read(), we stop when we encounter \n. No exceptions.
        # Note that it's still possible we run out of memory if a large enough
        # size is used and we don't find a newline.
        # A trailing newline is kept in the string.
        read_size = 0;
        if size >= 0:
            # If size is given try to find up to size
            temp_read = self.peek(size)
            newline = temp_read.find(b'\n')
            if newline == -1:
                read_size = len(temp_read)
            else:
                read_size = newline+1
        else:
            # Keep increasing size by 4K until newline is found
            newline = -1
            while newline == -1:
                read_size += 4096
                temp_read = self.peek(read_size);
                newline = temp_read.find(b'\n')
            read_size = newline+1
        return self.read(read_size);     

    def seek(self, pos, whence=0):
        if whence==2:  # Seek from end of infinite file doesn't make sense
            UnsupportedOperation("BufferedStringReader does not support seek(whence=2)")
        elif whence==1:
            self.pos = max(self.pos+pos, 0)
        elif whence==0:
            if pos < 0:
                raise OSError("[Errno 22] Invalid argument")
            self.pos = pos
        else:
            raise ValueError("whence value " + str(whence) + " unsupported")

        self.stringio.seek(min(self.pos, self.stringlen), 0)
        self.reader.seek(max(self.pos - self.stringlen, 0), 0)
        self.readerpos = max(self.pos - self.stringlen, 0)
        self.__update_state__()
        return self.pos

    def seekable(self):
        return True

    def tell(self):
        return self.pos

    def truncate(self, pos=None):
        raise UnsupportedOperation("BufferedStringReader does not support truncate()")

    def write(self, s):
        raise UnsupportedOperation("BufferedStringReader does not support write()")

    def writelines(self, s):
        raise UnsupportedOperation("BufferedStringReader does not support writelines()")

    def writable(self):
        return False



# To use:

reader = BufferedStringReader("something", "/dev/urandom", "rb")
print(reader)

assert reader.readable() == True
assert reader.seekable() == True
assert reader.writable() == False
assert reader.isatty() == False

assert reader.tell() == 0
assert reader.read(4) == b"some"
assert reader.tell() == 4

reader.seek(pos=-2, whence=1)
assert reader.read(2) == b"me"
reader.seek(pos=0, whence=0)

assert reader.tell() == 0
print(reader.read(12))  # "something<First 3 characters from /dev/urandom>"
assert reader.tell() == 12
print(reader.read(12))  # "<Next 12 characters from /dev/urandom>"
assert reader.tell() == 24

zero_array = bytearray(0)
assert reader.readinto(zero_array) == 0
assert zero_array == b''

zero_array = bytearray(10)
assert reader.readinto(zero_array) == 10
print(zero_array)

reader.seek(pos=0, whence=0)
assert reader.peek(4) == b"some"
assert reader.read(4) == b"some"
assert reader.tell() == 4

print(reader.peek(8)) # "thing<First 3 characters from /dev/urandom>"
print(reader.read(8)) # Note: This is a block device, so output may not be the same as above.
assert reader.tell() == 12
print(reader.peek(8)) # "FNext20 characters from /dev/urandom>"
assert reader.tell() == 12

reader.close()

reader = BufferedStringReader("something\nspam\neggs\n", "/dev/urandom", "rb")
assert reader.readlines() == b"something\n"
assert reader.readlines(3) == b"spa"
assert reader.readlines() == b"m\n"
assert reader.readlines(5) == b"eggs\n"

reader.detach()

reader = BufferedStringReader("something\nspam\neggs\n", "/dev/urandom", "rb")

try:
    reader.flush()
except UnsupportedOperation as e:
    print(e)

try:
    reader.getvalue()
except UnsupportedOperation as e:
    print(e)

try:
    reader.read(size=-1)
except UnsupportedOperation as e:
    print(e)

try:
    reader.read1(10)
except UnsupportedOperation as e:
    print(e)

try:
    reader.readinto1(10)
except UnsupportedOperation as e:
    print(e)

try:
    reader.seek(pos=100, whence=2)
except UnsupportedOperation as e:
    print(e)

try:
    reader.truncate(10)
except UnsupportedOperation as e:
    print(e)

try:
    reader.write('eggs')
except UnsupportedOperation as e:
    print(e)

try:
    reader.writelines('eggs')
except UnsupportedOperation as e:
    print(e)

try:
    reader = BufferedStringReader("something\nspam\neggs\n", "/dev/urandom", "wb")
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)
```

Here are some examples of using `BufferedStringReader`:

```
>>> reader = BufferedStringReader("something", "/dev/urandom", "rb")
>>> bytes_object = reader.read(20)
>>> # Because this is /dev/urandom the following output might be different than this.
>>> print(bytes_object)
b'somethingc\xab\xf6\xab\xea\xd1q C(\x05'
```